# Cimg link eclipse error

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, cimg

in ubuntu eclipse I would like to use theCImg lib:

My g++ opt:

```
   -I"/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/re_fol/CImgLib"
    -I"/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/re_fol/Eigen" -O0 -g3 -Wall
   -c -fmessage-length=0 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11   -lX11
  -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -llapack -lGLU -lGL -ldc1394  -L -lXext -pthread
```

STILL gets this error:

```
make all
Building target: resolution_F
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker

g++ -L/home/lukas/Desktop/CImg-1.7.1_pre033116 -o"resolution_F"
./re_fol/core.o ./re_fol/resolution_F.o
./re_fol/core.o: In function
`cimg_library::cimg::Mutex_info::trylock(unsigned int)':
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:2875:
undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
./re_fol/core.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_width()':
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7178:
undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7182:
undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
./re_fol/core.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_height()':
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7199:
undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'

/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7203:
undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
./re_fol/core.o: In function
`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_handle_events(_XEvent const*)':
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7230:
undefined reference to `XUnmapWindow'
/home/lukas/Desktop/ressss/resolution_F/Debug/../re_fol/CImg.h:7236:
```

I TRY EVERYTHING.restart, many options,.....gcc 4.6 or gcc 4.7...

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your code with the X11 and pthread library.
Probably you just have to add those compiler options somewhere in the preferences of your project :

```
-lpthread -lX11
```